# React with Context, reduce dispatch boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I was looking for a way to reduce the boilerplate when using React context. Normally, when dispatching actions, I do this:

```
    applicationDispatch({
      type: applicationActionTypes.setIsLoading,
      payload: !isLoading,
    });
```

So I tried this  (outside *and* inside of the component):

```
const useDispatch = (dispatch, method, payload) =>
  dispatch({
    type: applicationActionTypes[method],
    payload: payload,
  });
```

And tried to call it like this:

```
function App(){
const {application, applicationDispatch} = React.useContext(ApplicationStore)
const {isLoading} = application
const toggleLoading = ()=>useDipatch(applicationDispatch, applicationActionTypes.setIsLoading, payload)
...
}
```

That, of course, didn't work. I got the following error:

> React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "toggleLoading" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

So I tried to call it within the component:

```
return (
<div>
   {someBool && <Modal
          onClick={useDispatch(applicationDispatch, setIsLoading, !isLoading)}>
      ...
      </Modal>}
</div>
}
```

And I get the following error:

> React Hook "useDispatch" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useDispatch` function is not a "hook", so you shouldn't name it with the "use" prefix.

A more usual approach for what you are trying to achieve would be:

1- Create an actionCreator function:

```js
function runAction(method, payload) {
  return {
    type: applicationActionTypes[method],
    payload: payload,
  }
}
```

2- Dispatch using your actionCreator function:

```
return (
<div>
   {someBool && <Modal
          onClick={()=>applicationDispatch(runAction("setIsLoading", !isLoading))}>
      ...
      </Modal>}
</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like that implementation. So the "use..." part of the function name was signaling that it was a hook? Was there anything else that was signaling it as a hook?

Comment: Yes, the only signal was the "use" prefix. Hooks are very special functions, so they created this *convention that is enforced by the lint tooling*. Very helpful when you are really intending to use or create hook functions. And obviously the convention is also essential for people to easily identify that the function is a hook.